# how to get all the checked values and pass to angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, checkbox, controller

I have something like a post.
I want to add something like a bulk post delete.

I am thinking of making the post's id as value and when a button is clicked, all those checked values will be passed to the angular controller then pass it to the backend to search up for the ids selected and delete them.

But I am not sure how I am able to pass all those values

I only had something simple like this

```
<td><input type="checkbox" value="post.id" name="posts"></td>

<button class="btn btn-info pull-middle" ng-show="showDelBtnAndTableHeaders" ng-click="destroySelected(selectedPosts)">Delete Selected Posts</button>
```

I added something like this in the controller to test if I get it right that I get the array of values but done a few different tries and no luck

```
    $scope.destroySelected = function (array) {
        console.log(array);
        Post.destroySelected(array)
            .success(function () {

            })

    };
```

Can someone give me an idea on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show more codes ?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan which part should I show? there are quite a lot, don't want to flood the post

Answer (score 0):

Probably You put here: `value="post.id"`

Instead of this: `value="selectdPosts.id"`

or here: `ng-click="destroySelected(selectedPosts)"`

you should put: `ng-click="destroySelected(post)"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution to your problem:

[Working Example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tejassuthar/22oLstv7/9/)

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="PostController">
<label ng-repeat="post in posts">
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedPosts[]" value="{{post.id}}"ng-model="post.selected">{{post.name}}
</label>
<button ng-click="destroySelected()">Delete Selected Posts</button>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
myApp.controller('PostController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      // posts model
      $scope.posts = [
        { id: 1 , name: 'Manager',     selected: true },
        { id: 2 , name: 'Team Leader', selected: false },
        { id: 3 , name: 'Sr. Manager', selected: true },
        { id: 4 , name: 'Developer',   selected: false }
      ];

      // Remove Selected Posts
      $scope.destroySelected = function destroySelected(){
          angular.forEach($scope.posts, function (item) {

               // Check if Item is selected
               if(item.selected === true){
                   // Delete Item based on item.id 
                   alert('Deleted ItemId: '+item.id);
               }
          });
      } 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

please check out the plunker link in comment....as i dont know how to attacth here......i used a filter to fetch all selected id's and accessed in button click.so from here you can send those to your post call....